# WebForms page inside of Orchard CMS Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, orchardcms

I'm trying to include a webforms (.aspx) page inside of an Orchard 1.2 application.

I've tried adding back the aspx handler in the web.config

```
<add path="*.aspx" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" />
```

and added code to the Global.asax to try and get routing to ignore aspx requests

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
```

I'm still receiving a 404 response anytime I request the aspx page. How do I make this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a web.config that has worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers accessPolicy="Script">
        <add name="ASPX" path="*.aspx" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" preCondition="integratedMode" requireAccess="Script"/>
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks Bertrand. I got this working by adding the handler in the web.config of Orchard.Web and placing my webform pages in a directory in the same project.

Answer (score 0):

Using the above as the complete Web.cofig of Orchard.web produces the result but stops Orchard pages being displayed.

Adding this handler to the original Web.config of Orchard.Web still produces a Resource cannot be found error when browsing to ASPX pages (orchard pages are fine).

By removing

```
<httpHandlers>
      <!-- see below -->
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

I can browse to both Orchard Pages and ASPX pages by using the method above.

Thanks

Complete Web.config from Orchard.Web

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>

    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="log4net.Config" value="Config\log4net.config" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="Orchard.Mvc.ViewEngines.Razor.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
        <add namespace="Orchard.Mvc.Html"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <!-- 
        Set default transaction timeout to 30 minutes so that interactive debugging 
        is easier (default timeout is less than one minute)
  -->
  <system.transactions>
    <defaultSettings timeout="00:30:00"/>
  </system.transactions>
  <system.web>
    <!--<trust level="Medium" originUrl="" />-->

    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
    -->
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" batch="true" numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart="250">
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".csproj" type="Orchard.Environment.Extensions.Compilers.CSharpExtensionBuildProviderShim"/>
      </buildProviders>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <remove assembly="System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <remove assembly="System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <remove assembly="System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <remove assembly="System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <remove assembly="System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <remove assembly="System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <remove assembly="System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <remove assembly="System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <remove assembly="System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <remove assembly="System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <remove assembly="System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <remove assembly="System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <remove assembly="System.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <remove assembly="System.ServiceModel.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <remove assembly="System.WorkflowServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <remove assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <remove assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <remove assembly="System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
    -->
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Users/Account/AccessDenied" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>

    <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.
    -->
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
        <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
        <add namespace="Orchard.Mvc.Html"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>


    <httpModules>
      <add name="WarmupHttpModule" type="Orchard.WarmupStarter.WarmupHttpModule, Orchard.WarmupStarter, Version=1.0.20, Culture=neutral"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
  -->
  <system.webServer>

    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WarmupHttpModule" />
      <add name="WarmupHttpModule" type="Orchard.WarmupStarter.WarmupHttpModule, Orchard.WarmupStarter, Version=1.0.20, Culture=neutral"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Script">
      <add name="ASPX" path="*.aspx" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" preCondition="integratedMode" requireAccess="Script"/>
      <add name="NotFound" path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="App_Data/Dependencies"/>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"  />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```