# WebForms page inside of Orchard CMS Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms, orchardcms

I am attempting to add a aspx page inside orchard cms application. I have placed my aspx page in a folder /Web/Test.aspx in the Orchard.Web web application. Note: I am using the source of orchard at the moment. I also added the necessary handler, as posted in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6637696), in the system.webServer tag in the config. Currently getting 'The resource cannot be found.'

Here is what my web config looks like around the system.webServer tag.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers accessPolicy="Script">
            <!-- already listed, not added by me -->
            <clear/>
            <!-- added by me -->
            <add name="ASPX" path="*.aspx" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" preCondition="integratedMode" requireAccess="Script">
            <!-- already listed, not added by me -->
            <add name="NotFound" path="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" requireAccess="Script"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I'm I missing anything?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637696/webforms-page-inside-of-orchard-cms-application

Answer (score 0):

Remove the clear tag and the Notfound handler and then try again.