# Orchard, WebForms and iFrames

Tags: content-management-system, orchardcms

I am trying to embed an iFrame into a Orchard CMS section (same domain - controls live in a subdirectory off the main Orchard installation). I found two threads on here that talk about the issue I'm having (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735379/webforms-page-inside-of-orchard-cms-application) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735379/webforms-page-inside-of-orchard-cms-application)), but I'm still running into issues. The pages I am trying to load in the iFrame are standard WebForms and require both WebResource.axd and ScriptResource.axd. I managed to get WebResource.axd working, but ScriptResource is returning a 500 Internal Server Error (according to Chrome), but I can't figure out what's causing the 500 or what the real error is. The relevant entry from my web.config is below - any suggestions?

```
<handlers accessPolicy="Script">
  <!-- clear all handlers, prevents executing code file extensions, prevents returning any file contents -->
  <clear />

  <!-- Custom Controls -->
  <add name="ASPX" path="*.aspx" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" preCondition="integratedMode" requireAccess="Script"/>
  <add name="WebResource" path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  <add name="ScriptResource" path="ScriptResource.axd" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" />

  <!-- Everything below added from Orchard -->
  <!-- Return 404 for all requests via managed handler. The url routing handler will substitute the mvc request handler when routes match. -->
  <!--<add name="NotFound" path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" requireAccess="Script" />-->

  <!-- WebApi -->
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: Turn custom errors off to get a proper stack trace.
But really your best bet is to just put your webforms stuff in a completely separate application. You are already using it in an iframe so it should not matter.

Comment: I've tried that (and still am playing with it), but no luck. The issue seems to be the parent config's <clear /> entry. When inside the sub application (not virtual directory), ScriptResource.axd returns a 404 until I remove the <clear /> tag from the parent inside system.webServer/handlers, but removing this breaks Orchard pretty bad. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Not an application *under* the Orchard application, a separate one, outside of it. If you put Orchard under \Inetpub\wwwroot, then that's not a great idea in the first place. It's better to create vdirs somewhere else or under that and point IIS to those directories. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't use inetpub (agree that it is bad practice), but I did have the application underneath. Before attempting this I upgraded to .Net 4.5 RTM (was on the Beta and didn't realize it) and since the upgrade I'm getting a new issue and moving it didn't fix that issue. I created a second SO question for that though, since technically this was working until I got a little further into it. That question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638627/registerclientscriptresource-nullreferenceexception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining Bertrand's suggestion and a lot of playing around, I ended up finding a solution to this.

First, the custom stuff will need to be in a subfolder and inside IIS you can switch that subfolder over to an application (not a virtual directory). For a little extra peace of mind, I also gave it a dedicated app pool so if something did get weird with it the main site wouldn't go down.

The next parts involve a couple of steps - mostly because of that <clear /> entry in system.webServer/handlers. Removing this in the parent app breaks Orchard, but having it in broke my child app since it inherits all the settings from the parent. To get around this, my child app had to have the following system.webServer configuration:

```
    <system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="NotFound" />
    <add name="ASPX" path="*.aspx" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" preCondition="integratedMode" requireAccess="Script"/>
  <add name="WebResource" path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </handlers>
  <modules>
    <remove name="WarmupHttpModule" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

I used the SO link referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822733/ajaxtoolkit-iis7-asp-net-4-0-sys-is-not-defined-handler-mapping-issue) to find the "real" ScriptResource.axd reference that was needed and it looks like everything is working.