# RegisterClientScriptResource NullReferenceException in a Child IIS Application

Tags: c#, orchardcms, asp.net-4.5

I upgraded from .Net 4.5 Beta to the RTM version, and now when I have a standard WebForm page where I had a generic <asp:RequiredFieldValidator /> tag I get a NullReferenceException that looks like this:

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ValidatorCompatibilityHelper.RegisterClientScriptResource(Control control, String resourceName) +180
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +253
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +170
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +255
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +255
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +255
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +255
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4047

I even created a sample page (no master pages - just the below HTML) and as soon as I add the validator I get the above error. Here is it's HTML:

```
<form runat="server">
     <asp:Textbox runat="server" ID="txTest" />
     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txTest" />
</form>
```

Other pages for other sites on this server work fine, so I'm suspecting this is related to it being a sub application within IIS and the parent app is Orchard. Any suggestions on how I might resolve this? Since it's just a standard tag I don't even know where to start looking.

**Edit**: I figured out what was causing it to break, though I'm hoping someone from the Orchard team could clarify why this was done. Inside the default config there is a section under compilation for assemblies and inside that there is a number of assemblies that are removed. I took the whole list out and my inner page worked so I started adding them in one at a time and it broke when I added the remove entry for System.Web.Extensions. I can easily add it in to my child app, but I'm curious as to why it would've been removed in the first place. Here is what it typically looks like and I removed the entry for System.Web.Extensions to make my child app work:

```
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" batch="true" numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart="250" optimizeCompilations="true">
  <buildProviders>
    <add extension=".csproj" type="Orchard.Environment.Extensions.Compilers.CSharpExtensionBuildProviderShim" />
  </buildProviders>
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <remove assembly="System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <remove assembly="System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <remove assembly="System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <remove assembly="System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <remove assembly="System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <remove assembly="System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <remove assembly="System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <remove assembly="System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <remove assembly="System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <remove assembly="System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <remove assembly="System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <remove assembly="System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <remove assembly="System.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <remove assembly="System.ServiceModel.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <remove assembly="System.WorkflowServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <remove assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <remove assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <remove assembly="System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Comment: Is the parent application running the same version of .NET? In general, the child web.config adds to or replaces what's in the parent web.config, so the parent can heavily affect the child. Also, is the child an application, or only a virtual directory?

Comment: Yep, both are configured for 4.0 in IIS, though they are 4.5. It is configured as an application, not just a virtual directory.

Comment: So, what happens if you target .NET 4.0? Or if you configure them both for 4.5?

Comment: I was under the impression 4.5 is like 3.5 was in IIS - I can't select it directly. My only options are 2.0 and 4.0. I did try changing the child project to 4.0 inside VS, but that made no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Orchard's web.config, some assemblies are explicitly removed as they are not used by Orchard itself. If you need them then it's safe to re-enable them.

Comment: That's what I did to resolve this. Why is this done? Is it for better performance or..?

Comment: Opt-in is always better for both security and performance. Doesn't make it more secure or faster, but for sure it can't make it worse.