# Orcahrd CMS(WebForm)

Tags: asp.net, orchardcms

Is there any approach to integrate the web from on orchard Themes? 
I'm working on orchard application.To that application I needs to integrate some web forms. I was able to integrate, But I'm not able to see the inside the orchard theme. the page is rendering as a common webform(aspx) page as I need it on orchard theme.

Comment: I don't think you can use .cshtml (where orchard themes are written in) files as masterpage on a webform

Comment: As Bertrand answered, there is no easy way of integrating webforms into MVC upon which Orchard is built. It is possible though, but very labor-intensive and highly depends on your current architecture and goal.

Answer (score 1):

WebForms are not supported in Orchard. Orchard is built on MVC, and its views must be built using Razor.

Comment: Then what does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6639597/3153169) mean? Or do you mean webforms cannot **integrate** with orchard pages/shapes?

Comment: It's possible to render aspx pages, but postbacks won't work.

Comment: And there will be no Orchard integration. It's an extraordinarily bad idea that should be avoided at all cost.